# Empty UITableView with tableFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tablefooterview

I have a `UITableView` in which I want to show a message when the `dataSource` is empty. I do this with the well-known method of setting the backgroundView using the following extension:

```
extension UITableView {

    func setEmptyMessage(_ message: String, _ image: String) {
        let emptyView: UIView = {
            let emptyView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
            return emptyView
        }()

        let contentView: UIView = {
            let contentView = UIView()
            contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return contentView
        }()

        let messageLabel = UILabel()
        let messageCommentStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        messageCommentStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.2

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: lightFeedUserNameFontColor, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: messageCommentStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: normalFontSize), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))

        messageLabel.attributedText = attributedString
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: normalFontSize)
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()
        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let errorImage: UIImageView = {
            let errorImage = UIImageView()
            errorImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return errorImage
        }()

        self.backgroundView = emptyView

        emptyView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(errorImage)
        contentView.addSubview(messageLabel)

        contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.leadingAnchor, constant: normalSpacing * 3).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.trailingAnchor, constant: -(normalSpacing * 3)).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: errorImage.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        messageLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func restore() {
        self.backgroundView = nil
    }
}
```

And I set it like this:

```
if(tableData.isEmpty) {
    self.tableView.setEmptyMessage("No results!", "none")
} else {
    self.tableView.restore()
}

self.tableView.reloadData()
```

No big deal, we all have seen this and probably used it. And it works great. However, I now have a `UIButton` on the bottom placed in the tableFooterView. This button stays on top of the `UITableView` because it automatically positions itself right under the last cell, which is precisely what I want when there is data, but now the empty message is shown in the middle of the screen while the button is above it. How can I fix this so there is a sort of frame when the dataSource is empty?

To illustrate:
[image: Current state]

Comment: Instead of using backgroundView when datasource is empty, return 1 table view cell with the no results message

Comment: when data  is empty .., add `tblView.footerView = UIView()`

Answer (score 0):

So now you are setting your tableView backgroundView to your emptyView. You can take a look on your dataSource and if it's empty - just return new cell for empty state with this message.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count > 0 ? dataSource.count : 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if dataSource.count.isEmpty 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmptyCell")
        cell.textLabel.text = "No Results!"
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomeCell")
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this approach, but now I receive the following error: **Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).** when I insert a new section. Happens probably because tableData (dataSource) is empty at first, but then I append only one item. Should I have one item in my tableData even if the table is empty then?

Comment: You do not need to insert new section. You can reload your tableView
with `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Your numbers of sections are still 1. And depending on your data source if it's empty or not you return cell for your item or your empty cell

Comment: Upon insertion (or deletion) of a section I call beginUpdates and endUpdates with the animated insertion block inside, so reloadData() is not used when adding or deleting a section. I’ll try calling reloadData() when the dataSource count is changed to 1 and otherwise call the insertion block.

Comment: try tableView.reloadData() or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrowsatindexpaths?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension

```
extension UITableView
{
    func addErrorMessageLabel(noDataText:String = "No data available")->UILabel
    {
        let noDatalabel:UILabel!
        noDatalabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width/2-200, y: self.frame.size.height/2-50, width: 400, height: 100))
        noDatalabel.textColor = textThemeColor
        noDatalabel.text=noDataText
        noDatalabel.numberOfLines=0
        noDatalabel.textAlignment = .center
        noDatalabel.isHidden=true
        self.addSubview(noDatalabel)
        self.alignCenterToSuperView(item: noDatalabel, horizentally: true, vertically: true,height: 100,width: 400)
        return noDatalabel
    }
    func alignCenterToSuperView(item:UIView,horizentally:Bool,vertically:Bool , height:Int, width:Int)
{
    if horizentally
    {
        item.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([xConstraint])
    }
    if vertically
    {
        item.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([yConstraint])
    }
    let Height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant:CGFloat(height))
    item.addConstraint(Height)
    let Width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant:CGFloat(width))
    item.addConstraints([Width,Height])
}
}
```

In your ViewController create

```
    var noDataLabel:UILabel!
```

In your ViewDidLoad

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    noDataLabel = tableView.addErrorMessageLabel()
    noDataLabel.text = "No data found" // or your message
}
```

And final step

```
    if(tableData.isEmpty) {
    noDataLabel.isHideen = false
} else {
    noDataLabel.isHideen = true
}
```